# Power BI Service to GCP (BigQuery)

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have created this power bi report with data in GCP-BigQuery and once is deployed in app.powerbi.com i get this weird error in datasets when i run the report.
Not sure what it is ... anyone seeing this error with datasource as Big query  ??
Error " Failed to update data source credentials: [DataSource.Error] Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token' (400): Bad Request"

It works fine on power bi desktop but NOT on service ? ? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR55P.png)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a gateway on Power BI Service or a Premium workspace?
If yes, you need to define the connector in Power BI Service to refresh the dataset reading data from GCP.
If not, you need one of those two.

Comment: No gateway... Straight from service to GCP... Direct Query mode

Comment: Then you need to setup the cloud-to-cloud connection between Power BI service and GCP otherwise PBI Service does not know where/how to get those data! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-bigquery

Comment: thank you but any pointers of how to setup cloud-to-cloud connection between Power BI service and GCP  ??  highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, authorization from incognito mode helped me